# How to write a schema to constrain some of the properties with one/any of the sub-schemas?

Tags: yaml, jsonschema

Can I validate both

```
name: "range_1"
step: 1
start: 0
stop: 10
```

and

```
name: "range_2"
step: 1
center: 5
span: 5
```

with something like

```
properties:
    name:
        type: "string"
    stop:
        type: number
    oneOf:
    -   start:
            type: number
        step:
            type: number
    -   center:
            type: number
        span:
            type: number
```

For now I am using [jsonschema](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) in Python, but it complains `jsonschema.exceptions.SchemaError: <the array in oneOf> is not of type 'object', 'boolean'`.

Validating against `name` and `step` only or validating against all possible keys apparently works but they both seem sub-optimal for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `oneOf` keyword out of the `properties` object as everything in the `properties` object is interpreted as an expected value in your data.

Additionally, it makes sense to add an `required` property to make the values mandatory. Finally, if you want to make sure that no other values are excepted, you can use `additionalProperties: false`. Note though, that you have to repeat the "parent" properties in the `oneOf` schemas again. For further reading I recommend [this example](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#unevaluated-properties).

Put all together, you could use the following schema (see [live example here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/uzdFW857)):

```yaml
---
properties:
  name:
    type: string
  step:
    type: number
oneOf:
- properties:
    name: true
    step: true
    start:
      type: number
    stop:
      type: number
  required:
  - start
  - stop
  additionalProperties: false
- properties:
    name: true
    step: true
    center:
      type: number
    span:
      type: number
  required:
  - center
  - span
  additionalProperties: false
```

Comment: So there is no way to extract the common properties. And what does `name: true` mean?

Comment: You can extract them by using [`unevaluatedProperties: false`](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#unevaluated-properties) instead of `additionalProperties: false`. However, it is only available in newer schema versions. `name: true` means property "name" can be anything within the scope of this sub-schema which makes the property "visible" to the local `additionalProperties`. The sub-schemas of the first `property` and the `oneOf` get layered on top of each other in an additive fashion.